# remote mysql import: No such file or directory

Tags: mysql, ssh

This is a weird issue. I have a build script which is dumping the database to a sql file (which contains 3 databases).

Then I upload the file to staging server (works) and when I run or execute the command:

```
sshpass -p 'webmin' ssh webmin@apps.mydomain.local mysql -u root < /var/www/complete_db.sql
```

I get an error:

```
bash: /var/www/complete_db.sql: No such file or directory
```

Which is not correct - it most certainly is on the staging server at that path. If I remote into the server and execute:

```
mysql -u root < /var/www/complete_db.sql
```

It imports as expected and everything works fine...

Even if I do

```
sshpass -p 'webmin' ssh webmin@apps.mydomain.local ls -al /var/www
```

I can clearly see the file on the server...any ideas?

Comment: Awesome - that was it darn it - why didn't I think of that :) Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem. I should have added it as an answer, will do that now

Answer (score 0):

My bet would be that the `< /var/www/complete_db.sql`part is being passed to sshpass and not as part of the command that is getting sent to the remote server.

Some clever use of quoting can probably fix that - I'd try putting the entire remote command into quotes:

```
sshpass -p 'webmin' ssh webmin@apps.mydomain.local "mysql -u root < /var/www/complete_db.sql"
```